# How can I filter a 2d array in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to filter data from 2d array according to the string/text which is entered by user like if we write the name or phone number of a person it contact detail is searched and shown.

**In 2D array  [["Name","Phone number"]]. if number or name which is entered by the user is matched with any value then that will store in an other array.**

```
var data : [[String]] = [["AB","+923476760226"],["Umair","+923366111830"],.......]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is the desired output? Please provide sample input/output combinations to make your intentions 100% clear. And please show your current code which might not yet work but at least shows some effort of yours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to filter a 2D array is to filter twice, once per level.

```
var data = [["AB","+923476760226"],["Umair","+923366111830"]]
let searchString = "+9234"

var result = data.filter { (dataArray:[String]) -> Bool in
    return dataArray.filter({ (string) -> Bool in
        return string.containsString(searchString)
    }).count > 0
}
```

This code just filters out all the items that has at least one item that contains the searchString.

However, I'd like to say that you really should keep the name and number in a separate class or struct and build some mach function so that you don't have to filter twice

```
struct Contact{
    let name: String
    let number: String

    init(name: String, number:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }

    func match(string:String) -> Bool {
        return name.containsString(string) || number.containsString(string)
    }
}


let properData = [Contact(name: "AB", number: "+923476760226"), Contact(name: "Umair", number: "+923366111830")]

let properResult = properData.filter { (contact) -> Bool in
    return contact.match(searchString)
}
```

This will make your code a bit cleaner in the long run and it's a good idea to work with classes and struct like this in general

Comment: I spent 4 hours trying other things and I did it! but these solutions are better. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The better way to use `[["Name","Phone number"]]` in application is to use array of dictionary, or array of tuples.

In case of array of dictionary, you structure will be like:

```
var record1:[String:String] = ["name":"AB", "Phonenumber":"+923476760224"]
var record2:[String:String] = ["name":"AC", "Phonenumber":"+923476760225"]
var record3:[String:String] = ["name":"BC", "Phonenumber":"+923476760226"]
var data : [[String:String]] = [record1, record2, record3];
```

now you can apply predicates to use filters.

```
let pred = (NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "name", "AB")!)
```

or if you want to use tuples, you can refer to 
[Apply NSPredicate on [(String, Array<String>)]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504186/apply-nspredicate-on-string-arraystring)

Comment: Also please refer the second solution provided by @Moriya. That is the best way to handle the collections. As you can extend the feature of models, and can create custom methods on the same, if required in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me with miner changes. Thank you.  @Moriya                          There is the code which work for me in Swift 1.2.
i'm using this in searchBar.

```
    var data = [["AB","+923476760226"],["Umair","+923366111830"]]

   func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)           {

           var result = data.filter { (dataArray:[String]) -> Bool in
            return dataArray.filter({ (str : String) -> Bool in
                    return str.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil    
                }).count > 0
                }
        tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is next. With the result of one dimension array using [arr.flatMap()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap) for escaping from 2d array, as it's ok for my task.
Maybe it will be helpful for someone )

```
struct Citizen {
    let name: String
    let age: String

    func match(string: String) -> Bool {
        return name.lowercased().contains(string.lowercased()) || age.lowercased().contains(string.lowercased())
    }
}

let arr = [[Citizen(name: "Jak", age: "20"), Citizen(name: "Barbara", age: "24")], [Citizen(name: "Bob", age: "50"), Citizen(name: "Sarah", age: "48")]]

let flatArr = arr.flatMap { $0 }
let searchName = "B"
let filteredArr = flatArr.filter{ (item) -> Bool in
            return item.matchName(string: searchName)
        }

print(filteredArr)

//[Citizen(name: "Barbara", age: "24"), Citizen(name: "Bob", age: "50")]
```